# Python3: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to get a code working which uses `ruamel_yaml` apparently, however my system somehow does not find it, although I have it installed:

```
sudo -H pip3 install ruamel.yaml
```

returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.15.37)
```

but when I execute the code:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'
```

I installed it using `pip3`, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.

I did try uninstalling and reinstalling it, did not change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well exactly, there is `import ruamel_yaml as yaml`. Should it be changed to the one with dot?

Comment: You were actually right, if you add this as an answer I'll accept, it did work when I changed it to 'import ruamel.yaml'.

Comment: Was the underscore a typo, or did you read somewhere that it should be `import ruamel_yaml as yaml`? In the latter case I would like to contact the authors (assuming I did not write this incorrectly in the ruamel.yaml documentation myself).

Comment: No, it is not a typo. In many repositories you can find people referring it as `ruamel_yaml`. I guess it was an old notation or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you seem have an `import ruamel_yaml` statement. you should replace that with:

```
import ruamel.yaml
```